# PyTorch dataloader performance slump on HDD

Tags: performance, io, pytorch

I've just built a new PC for DL and I'm testing it on the official [Imagenet example](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py) from PyTorch. I'm seeing reasonable performance when the dataset resides on my SSD (`GoodRam IRDM Pro 240GB SATA3 (IRP-SSDPR-S25B-240)`), but it becomes ridiculously slow on my HDD (`Toshiba P300 (HDWD120UZSVA)`). It seems to be all about the `DataLoader`. Of course, SDD is expected to perform better than HDD, but I don't think this workload should even be bottlenecked by disc read (on other machines I used, it was either GPU bound, or CPU bound due to preprocessing), let alone to this extent. To investigate, I wrote a quick iterator wrapper to time the dataloader calls

```
def time_iter(iter):
    while True:
        start = time.time()
            item = next(iter)
            print('Yielding in', time.time() - start)
            yield item
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

And checked the results by evaluating a pretrained net on Imagenet. The results on HDD:

```
jatentaki@Dzik:~/Programs/pytorch-examples/imagenet$ python main.py --pretrained -e -b 768 -j 10 ~/2tb/Datasets/ILSVRC2012/
=> using pre-trained model 'resnet18'
Yielding in 94.4384298324585
Test: [0/66]    Time 97.014 (97.014)    Loss 0.6302 (0.6302)    Prec@1     82.943 (82.943)  Prec@5 95.573 (95.573)
Yielding in 0.00038623809814453125
Yielding in 0.00019431114196777344
Yielding in 0.0001766681671142578
Yielding in 0.0002028942108154297
Yielding in 0.00017595291137695312
Yielding in 0.00017023086547851562
Yielding in 0.000179290771484375
Yielding in 0.00019288063049316406
Yielding in 0.00017714500427246094
Yielding in 85.04550909996033
Test: [10/66]   Time 85.408 (16.858)    Loss 1.1352 (0.8930)    Prec@1 69.661 (77.190)  Prec@5 91.927 (92.779)
Yielding in 0.15804052352905273
Yielding in 0.00020647048950195312
Yielding in 2.0329136848449707
Yielding in 0.00020360946655273438
```

The ~90 second spikes consistently appear every 9 iterations. On SDD:

```
jatentaki@Dzik:~/Programs/pytorch-examples/imagenet$ python main.py --pretrained -e -b 768 -j 10 ~/FastDatasets/
=> using pre-trained model 'resnet18'
Yielding in 11.228104829788208
Test: [0/66]    Time 14.272 (14.272)    Loss 0.6302 (0.6302)    Prec@1 82.943 (82.943)  Prec@5 95.573 (95.573)
Yielding in 0.00038361549377441406
Yielding in 0.00030112266540527344
Yielding in 0.0002224445343017578
Yielding in 0.0002486705780029297
Yielding in 0.00018787384033203125
Yielding in 0.0002593994140625
Yielding in 0.00020194053649902344
Yielding in 0.0003197193145751953
Yielding in 0.00019288063049316406
Yielding in 3.4066810607910156
Test: [10/66]   Time 4.013 (1.946)  Loss 1.1352 (0.8930)    Prec@1 69.661     (77.190)  Prec@5 91.927 (92.779)
Yielding in 1.5148968696594238
Yielding in 0.0003371238708496094
Yielding in 0.0002467632293701172
```

Other diagnostics: iotop total disk read peaks at 12-14M/s for HDD and 100-120M/s for SDD. `hdparm` results:

```
jatentaki@Dzik:~$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: # SSD
Timing cached reads:   20976 MB in  2.00 seconds = 10503.39 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 512 MB in  1.02 seconds = 501.77 MB/sec

jatentaki@Dzik:~$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: # HDD
Timing cached reads:   19484 MB in  2.00 seconds = 9755.75 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 586 MB in  3.01 seconds = 194.69 MB/sec
```

What is a possible cause of the problems? I am considering improper installation/synergy between the hardware pieces (I'm a total hardware noob) or some issues with how the DataLoader works. Another possibility is improperly configured OS (Xubuntu 18.04 LTS). Apparently there's a lot of caching going on (all the 0.000...s yields), could it go wrong?

System: Xubuntu 18.04 LTS
PyTorch: 0.4.1, from Anaconda, with CUDA 9.2 and 396 nvidia driver.
GPU: GTX 1080 Ti